# Element link is missing required attribute properly

Tags: css, html, validation, hyperlink

I've got 3 of this error when validating.

DOCTYPE: HTML5

**Error: Element link is missing required attribute property.**

```
<link type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/tabs/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

So I've used rel - type - href and one of them has the media attribute. What others I have to use in this case?

And I don't get why I don't get the same error for the other links I've used only with the same attributes...
Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you have a `link` element inside `body` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in the error message is outdated. Error messages are apparently not updated as fast as the basic functionality of the validator. The validator is actually validating against HTML5 + RDFa, and RDFa defines the `property` attribute.

Put you `<link>` in the `<head>` at the top of the document.

In HTML5 the `link` element is allowed in the document body but with an `itemprop` attribute.

Comment: Oh, I've found out those links were in the footer.php so when I put it to header.php at the head section it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you post all non-validating code? Because this validates, try it out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>sample</title>
<link type="text/css" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/tabs/js/easyResponsiveTabs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/aykamakina/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
</html>
```